# get id from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this code, how can I get the value of `user.Id` passed in the function `ng-click="UpdateUser()"` ?

> ```html
> > 
> >     <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: search ">
> >     <td>{{ user.Id }}</td>
> >     <td><button type="button" ng-click="UpdateUser()" >Update</button></td>
> > <tr>
> >
> ```

Comment: `<button type="button" ng-click="UpdateUser(user.Id)" >Update</button>`

Comment: @AbuTaha Can you provide the `users` array?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. : $http.get('/api/users')
              .success(function (response) { $scope.users = response; ...etc.

Comment: @AbuTaha I mean the exact response. The `users` array. Not the call function.

Comment: @AbuTaha Can you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(users));`?

Comment: [{"Id":2609,"FullName":"Hasan Ibn Alhaitham","Email":"abas@farnas.com","Mobile":"5642597952","Birthdate":"1966-06-15T21:00:00.000Z","Gender":"Male","AcademicLevel":"Master"},{"Id":2615,"FullName":"Welcome page","Email":"welcome@page.com","Mobile":"3243654645","Birthdate":"2015-06-09T21:00:00.000Z","Gender":"Male","AcademicLevel":"High School"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the `user.id` to `updateUser()`.

Check if your **codes** are like the codes below.

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/q60et8qx/8/).**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="YourCtrl">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users| filter: search">
            <td>{{ user.Id}}</td>
            <td><button type="button" ng-click="updateUser(user.Id)" >Update</button></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    Selected UserId: {{selectedUserId}}
</div>
```

**Your Controller**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.users = [
            {
                "Id": 2609,
                "FullName": "Hasan Ibn Alhaitham",
                "Email": "abas@farnas.com",
                "Mobile": "5642597952",
                "Birthdate": "1966-06-‌​15T21:00:00.000Z",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "AcademicLevel": "Master"
            },
            {
                "Id": 2615,
                "FullName": "Welcome page",
                "Email": "welcome@page.com",
                "Mobile": "3243654645",
                "Birthdate": "2015-06-09T2‌​1:00:00.000Z",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "AcademicLevel": "High School"
            }
        ];

        $scope.updateUser = function(userId) {
            console.log(userId);
            $scope.selectedUserId = userId;
        };

        console.log($scope.users);

    }]);
```

I added `selectedUserId` variable to check if it reflects to the **view**.

**Note:** Please observe `camelCase` naming convention.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Update the `ng-click` of `button` as follow:

```
ng-click="UpdateUser(user.Id)"
//                   ^^^^^^^
```

**Code**

View:

```
<button ng-click="UpdateUser(user.Id)">Update</button>
//                           ^^^^^^^
```

Controller:

```
$scope.UpdateUser = function(userId) {
//                           ^^^^^^
    alert(userId);
};
```

Comment: @AbuTaha Do you get any error? Can you create `jsfiddle` demo?

Comment: yes, error = "Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined
    at n.$scope.UpdateUser "

Comment: @AbuTaha Then how can you get `error = "Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined at n.$scope.UpdateUser`. Please add complete code in question

Comment: that is why I am asking for help @Tushar